# Zap Python - auto generation

Tags: zap

I've seen there is a python project and it states it's auto generated.
https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-api-python
What was used to generate python from java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its generated from java using this code: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/blob/develop/zap/src/main/java/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/api/PythonAPIGenerator.java

Comment: FYI we are working on adding a OpenAPI definition for the ZAP API but its not completed yet.